# how can i set what time php should consider while fetching time from system

Tags: php

Like i have a issue that.

My code will not execute with remote host if there is more than 5 min difference b/w both system time.

But I do not have permission to set system time in my **centos** machine.

And my system time is 10 min faster than server.
So what i want is,

while executing my code on local ,
php should consider 6 min later from current system time.

e.g:-
if Current system time is 13:30

and server time is 13:20

so my script will not execute with remote

so i want to set that php should consider it 13:26 before executing code, but i do not want to change system time of my machine.

Comment: Would it not be vastly easier to simply change your code and make it less sensitive to the time difference?

Comment: How does the remote host know what time your server thinks it is?

Comment: @Pekka웃 , It is not my code, it is a library containing huge code and i do not know where to change.

Comment: when i execute my code on local it make a curl request and match both time @mcrumley

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make PHP listen to a different time. You may have to find the code

Comment: that's what i was asking..@Pekka웃